# Sony Vaio Model: PCG-4L1L Hard Drive replacement

Tags: ssd, compatibility, sony-vaio

I have the above described Sony Vaio. It was shipped with a 32GB SSD drive which now full.

I am very happy with the laptop and so I would like to upgrade the SSD to a larger capacity. Unfortunately, this is not supported by Sony in any way.

Can anyone point me to a SSD drive that will be compatible with the above model? (I just could not find the information on the internet after many hours of searching)

---

I found on [this (laptoppartsexpert)](http://www.laptoppartsexpert.com/c-54353-sony-vaio-pcg-4l1l-notebook-repair-parts-accessories.html) site that a 2.5" regular HD should fit, but I would prefer something more official than realising it is not a fit during the assembly...

I am not sure I don't require a 1.8" drive

Comment: Cant you just check which SSD is installed? Accessing the HDD/SSD is typically a 1 screw job

Comment: Frankly, I am not near the laptop and will not be in the next several days, but was hoping for an answer so I could order something online in the meantime